# Domination problem is NPC

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, algorithms, np-complete

I call the problem as DOM. Given a graph $G$ and an integer $d$, Decision problem DOM - "Does there exists a dominating set of size less than or equal to 'd' in G? " DOM is NP Complete problem. 
But, if we specify some class of graphs $G'$ and if we ask the same question, then DOM might be solved in polynomial time. 
(Eg : Given $C_n$, and an integer $d$ , you can verify DOM in polynomial time ) 
 Till date , for which all classes of graphs, DOM problem can be solved in polynomial time ? 
[Let me know where I can find research papers worked on this topic]

Answer (score 1):

I guess that related Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set) is a rather complete and up to date source.  According to it, a [minimum dominating set can be found in linear time in series-parallel graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set#Special_cases). On the other hand, even for planar graphs the problem remains NP-hard, but it [admits a polynomial-time approximation scheme (PTAS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set#Special_cases) and a [fixed-parameter algorithm is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set#Parameterized_complexity).